# What is the difference between following SQL queries containing REGEXP_LIKE()?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, regexp-like

```
select distinct first_name 
from EMPLOYEES 
where regexp_like(first_name,'^[^AEIOU]*[^aeiou]$');    

select distinct first_name 
from EMPLOYEES 
where regexp_like(first_name,'^[^AEIOU].*[^aeiou]$');
```

I am trying to find Employee's first name's that doesn't start with and end with a vowel. I came up with above queries. Now I have two questions:

1. Do the above statements return valid output (doesn't start and with vowel).
2. Do the above statements return same result always (I get same result when I tried).

But when I tried the below two queries they gave different outputs with respect to each other

```
select distinct first_name 
from EMPLOYEES 
where regexp_like(first_name,'^[AEIOU]*[aeiou]$');    

select distinct first_name 
from EMPLOYEES 
where regexp_like(first_name,'^[AEIOU].*[aeiou]$');
```

Comment: Please clarify your second question since you contradict yourself.  You get the same results but you get different results?

Comment: the above questions give same result to each other,below ones give different to one an other

Comment: That's where I'm confused - the two sets of queries are exactly the same that I can tell.  If there's a subtle difference please highlight it.

Comment: That said I will note that `^[^AEIOU]*[^aeiou]$` and `^[AEIOU].*[aeiou]$` will give different results.  The difference is what the middle `*` operator is applied to.

Comment: comment if you mean the first two queries give different answers "with respect to each other".

Comment: And I quote am asking the similarity among the first two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The two first queries don't give you valid ouput. They match names that start with lowercase vowels or end with uppercase vowels. And they don't give always the same result:

- Marcos is a match for the first and the second
- MARCOS is a match for the second and not the first
- allan is a match for both

2) The second pair presents different output for similar reasons.

You can try it yourself: [Regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: What if the name always starts with a capital letter.Is the query valid?

Comment: I didnt understand your points what are marcos, what is allan?

Comment: Yes, Rahul, if you can enforce that a name always start with an uppercase letter and always finishes with a lowercsase letter, the query is valid.

Comment: 'allan' is the example of a name that would prove your query wrong if you do not enforce uppercase letters.

Comment: For the second question, in the first query the star operator (zero or more) is applied to [AEIOU], whereas in the second query, the star operator is applied to the '.' (dot - any character).